# Comparison slider w/ backdrop filter blur doesn't work

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

I would like to have a slider comparison with blurred areas over a 360 scene in Three.JS

Currently, I have a comparison slider that works over a ThreeJS scene. I compare two areas of blur each time that represents two kinds of glasses. I use backdrop-filter to manage this blur and clip-path to do the comparison slider.

```
backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);

&&

backdrop-filter: blur(80px);
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(80px);
```

You can see my code here (remove background color if you just want to see the blurred areas) : https://codepen.io/guicolombel/pen/oNNgxNP

I would like the slider comparison to work with the blurs areas. Not being able to put a background-image or img, I have trouble seeing another way to do it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you been able to make it work on a simple background image? I'm afraid this question has nothing to do with Three.js, since it's the CSS rule `backdrop-filter` that you're having an issue with. I also recommend you clean up your codepen example to make it easier for people to be able to help you without digging through 280 lines of CSS rules. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Marquizzo It also doesn't work with a background image, however I put it in ThreeJS to see if anyone would have an idea directly in the canvas (shader, etc...). Indeed, I will lighten the CSS.